# RecyclerView decorator adding extra padding on refresh

Tags: android

So, I'm facing a weird problem while implementing RecyclerView in my project. I have a custom decorator to implement a consistent top and bottom padding and a rather different value of padding in between elements. Whenever I tap on refresh, i.e. fetch data from back-end and populate RecyclerView again, the padding increases and it keeps on increasing on each refresh.

[image: This is the correct way]

When I hit refresh (causing AsyncTask to execute again), the space between items increase. And it keeps on increase with each refresh.

[image: Padding between items increasing]

I have a typical RecyclerView like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Populating content inside RecyclerView is CardView with the following layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/cv"
android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLinearTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="17dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:textColor="@color/logo_black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv1"
            android:textColor="@color/logo_black"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <!-- More elements -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I am initializing and populating RecyclerView like this:

```
// In PostExecute of AsyncTask
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new FuelPricesRecycleViewAdapter(data);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
rv.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewItemDecoration(30, item_count - 1));
```

And this is what my RecyclerViewItemDecoration class looks like:

```
public class RecyclerViewItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space = 0;
    private int item_count = 0;
    private int ADDITIONAL_PADDING = 20;

    public RecyclerViewItemDecoration(int space, int item_count) {
        this.space = space;
        this.item_count = item_count;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if(parent.getChildPosition(view) != item_count)
             outRect.bottom = space;

         // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
         if(parent.getChildPosition(view) == 0)
             outRect.top = space + ADDITIONAL_PADDING;
         if(parent.getChildPosition(view) == item_count)
             outRect.bottom = space + ADDITIONAL_PADDING;
     }
 }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: anything you have found ?

Comment: Almost one years later, I'm facing the same issue do you call RecyclerView.scrollToPosition() after refreshing?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? Currently I'm calling `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount(), emptyList());` as a workaround. This will invalidate all items without rebinding the views because there is a payload. (the payload can be any non-null object). I would still like to find a better way.

Comment: i used clitopadding= true and that worked. i could not find a better way.

Answer (score 23):

This is happening because we are trying to add itemDecorator to the recycler view which already have itemDecorator added to it, check first if its already there then don't add again

```
if (0 == recyclerview.getItemDecorationCount()) {
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.divider)));
}
```

This 0 will be the number of itemDecorator we have in recycler view, most of the time it'll be 0.

Comment: That is the best answer :)

Answer (score 17):

You have to remove the item decoration before reseting new data.

`rv.removeItemDecoration(yourDecorator)`

Let me know if it works!

Comment: That worked for me :) <br>
I did following `for (int i = 0; i < mRecyclerView.getItemDecorationCount(); i++) {
mRecyclerView.removeItemDecorationAt(i);}`But I think it is better to just add a new Decorator if none exists yet. I like @Pankaj kumar answer.

Answer (score 15):

You are adding `Decoration` each time recyclerview is loaded.

Use one flag instead :

```
private boolean flagDecoration = false;

if(!flagDecoration)
{
    rv.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewItemDecoration(30, item_count - 1));
    flagDecoration = true;    
}
```

Comment: I have used this decoration file :
https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e

Comment: It works, it just needed to have flahDecoration declared as boolean. OP didn't even try past copy + paste Thanks @codevscolor saved me alot of annoyance in my app!

Comment: I would just moved it from onResume to onViewCreated. Thank you @codevscolor.

Comment: Thanks @codevscolor for showing me the right direction

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and I fixed that with the itemDecorationCount

```
if (recyclerView.itemDecorationCount == 0) {
            val itemDecorator = DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
            itemDecorator.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.recycler_divider))
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, the best solution is to make your item decoration while your are initializing your layout manager in the view holder , this resolves the problem you are facing
example

```
public class GridViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    RecyclerView grid_list;

    public GridViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.grid_list = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_item_grid_recycler_view);
        if (grid_list.getLayoutManager() == null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 4);
            grid_list.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            grid_list.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(4, 3, false));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue and resolved it by placing

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(current_activity);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

in `onPreExecute()` method.

Just give it a try if it works

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue. Fix it with if check

```
    if (recyclerView.getItemDecorationAt(0) == null) { // check decoration here
        FlexboxItemDecoration agentDividerItemDecoration = new FlexboxItemDecoration(rv.getContext());
        agentDividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_divider_flex_normal));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(agentDividerItemDecoration);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "initTagsView: ItemDecoration not null");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are adding various decorations.
I was having the same problem. What I did here and that worked out was:

1º - Declare the decoration before the onCreate () method:

```
public StickyHeaderDecoration mDecor;
public MyAdapterPinned MyAdapterPinned;
```

2º - Then I created a method that creates and populates my recycleview. In this method I check if I have already called mDecor. If so, I remove it. Otherwise, I create it. The code looks like this:

```
public void createRecyclerView(){
    //hide layout com progress
    hideLayoutProgressFull();

    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    myAdapterPinned = new MyAdapterPinned(getContext(), mList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapterPinned);

    if (mDecor != null)
        recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(mDecor);

    mDecor = new StickyHeaderDecoration(myAdapterPinned);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(mDecor);

    //hide progressDialog
    hideProgress();
}
```

NOTE: I am using an adapter that sets the title to each change but you can not interfere with the result. You can use your ordinary adapter. It worked for me. I hope it works for you too;